# Dropdown CSS menu isn't visible over a slideshow DIV

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

The title said everything, any ideas how can I fix it? Thanks. here's a print.

[image]

Comment: without your code or even better a fiddle it won't be possible to answer...

Answer (score 1):

set position relative or absolute to both of them and set z-index value higher to the dropdown menu

for more about z-index visit [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Answer (score 0):

I just can assume, without your code.

Try this in your CSS

```
.topNavigation{
   z-index:99999;
}
```

Just read about [Z-index Properties](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)
at the same time please concern about other css properties as well

Comment: is ther any reason to have the z-index so high? What ever happened to `z-index:100?;`

Comment: well, the top navigation will float on top and atleast other layers wont lay over with others. and in future other style classes may contain some z-index properties. so we can't assume just 100 for topNavigation. it is aways better to give some more than required